# How to verify optional objects in the json schema in Karate?

Tags: karate

Optional fields can be verified using # symbol (##number).
I need to verify optional object in my response.
listValues is an optional object in the response. How can I check this since I am getting the error as actual does not contain key - 'listValues' since first object does not have listValues. how to make this optional

```
{"filter": {
    "ITEM": {
      "ITEM": [
        
        {
          "m_operators": ["A", "B"],
          "operators": ["A1", "B1"],
          "logicalDataType": "STRING",
          "tableName": "ITEM"
        },
        {
          "m_operators": ["C", "D"],
          "operators": ["C1", "D1"],
          "logicalDataType": "STRING",
          "tableName": "ITEM"
        },
        {
          "m_operators": ["E", "F"],
          "operators": ["E1", "F1"],
          "logicalDataType": "String",
          "listValues": [
            {
              "m_key": "String",
              "m_value": "String"
            },
            {
              "m_key": "String",
              "m_value": "String"
            }
          ],
          "tableName": "ITEM"
        }

      ]
    }
  }}
```

```
   * def listValuesSchema = {"m_key": "#string", "m_value": "#string}
    * def itemsSchema = {"m_operators": "#[] #string", "operators": "#[] #string", "logicalDataType": "#string", "listValues": "#[] ##(listValuesSchema)", "tableName": "#string"}
    * def filterSchema = {"ITEM": {"ITEM": "#[] ##(itemsSchema)"}}
    * def jsonExpected = {"filter": "#(filterSchema)"}
    * match response == jsonExpected
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an edge case if you "compose" optional chunks in a `match`. Read [this explanation](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2000#issuecomment-1117621666).

So the solutions should be something like this:

```
* def filterSchema = ({"ITEM": {"ITEM": "#[] ##(itemsSchema)"}})
```

And then do the `match`

Comment: Here, listValues is the Json array consisting of multiple objects which has key value pairs.
For that I have used "#[ ] ##(listValuesSchema)".
Now if I want to make listValues optional, how should this be defined ?

Comment: @Beginner I think it should be `"##[] listValuesSchema"`