Karate DSL - Nested Json Assertion
How would one go about asserting this nested json response:
{
  "Artists": [
    {
      "id": "00024012-b5d8-4aa4-b2fa-763b17007c3d",
      "name": "Freddie Wilson",
      "articles": [
        {
          "Article": {
            "id": "1f174833-3f81-53af-9b11-25468fc61b93",
            "title": "Brena Light Star sells for $200,000"
          }
        },
        {
          "Article": null
        },
        {
          "Article": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Here is my current approach which returns false, although I'm expecting true.
Any help would be greatly appreicated, thanks.

$[0].articles[0].article | evaluated to 'false'
(MAP:STRING)



This would work. The round brackets are explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77021082/143475
* def article = { id: '#uuid', title: '#string' }
* def articleParent = ({ Article: '##(article)' })
* match each response.Artists == { id: '#uuid', name: '#string', articles: '#[] articleParent' }

Personally, I prefer to pre-process complex response chunks before running a simple match, because it is simpler and more readable. It does require you to divide-and-conquer instead of trying to match the entire response in "one shot", and there is nothing wrong with this approach. For example:
* def articles = response.Artists[0].articles.filter(x => x.Article)
* match each articles == { Article: { id: '#uuid', title: '#string' } }

Things like filter() are explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76091034/143475

Ah brilliant, that's done the trick nicely! Thanks Peter :)
